# Tkinter self.destroy callback failing on Frame subclass

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a tkinter widget that takes nested dictionaries as input and generates OptionMenus that continue to narrow down choices until the choice dictionaries culminate in a value.

So far, the widgets generate correctly, but are not destroyed correctly. I've currently removed widget regeneration based off changing choices as it would cause more and more widgets to appear each time a change was made.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/LUtbzAMJ) is the code, as it wasn't pasting here nicely.

```
import tkinter as tk
labelwidth = 20
inputwidth = 25
 
 
class DropDownWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, labeltext, optionType, options, command=""):
        if not isinstance(options, dict):
            print(options)
            raise TypeError("DropDownWidgets take dictionaries of the choices and the values they represent as keys and values")
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.optionType = optionType
        self.options = options
        self.optionKeys = list(options.keys())
        self.optionValues = list(options.values())
        self.dropDownDisplayed = tk.StringVar(self, self.optionKeys[0])
 
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=labeltext, width=labelwidth, justify="left", relief="groove", anchor="w")
        self.input = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.dropDownDisplayed, *list(options.keys()), command=command)  # , command=self.updateValue)
        self.input.config(width=inputwidth-7)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.input.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
 
    def updateValue(self, something):
        self.inputVar.set(self.options[self.dropDownDisplayed.get()])
 
    def replaceOptionMenu(self, options, command, *args):
        self.options = options
        self.input.grid_forget()
        self.dropDownDisplayed.set(list(options.keys())[0])
        self.input = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.dropDownDisplayed, *list(options.keys()), command=command)
        self.input.config(width=inputwidth - 7)
        self.input.grid(row=0, column=2)
 
    def replaceOptionMenuNoCmd(self, options):
        self.options = options
        self.input.grid_forget()
        self.dropDownDisplayed.set(list(options.keys())[0])
        self.input = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.dropDownDisplayed, *list(options.keys()))
        self.input.config(width=inputwidth - 7)
        self.input.grid(row=0, column=2)
 
    def value(self):
        return self.optionType(self.options[self.dropDownDisplayed.get()])
 
    def setValue(self, value):
        self.dropDownDisplayed.set(value)
 
 
class MultiDropDownWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, options, isChild=False):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, relief="raised", bg="blue")
        self.originalOptions = options
        if isChild is False:
            self.root = self
        else:
            self.root = parent.root
 
        if isinstance(options, dict):
            if isinstance(list(options.values())[0], dict):
                self.options = {key: key for key in options.keys()}
                self.hasChild = True
            else:
                self.options = {key: value for key, value in options.items()}
                self.hasChild = False
        #
        else:
            self.options = options
 
        if self.hasChild:
            self.dropDown = DropDownWidget(self.root, "Choice", str, self.options,
                                           command=lambda x: self.destroyChildren())  # self.updateChild)
        else:
            self.dropDown = DropDownWidget(self.root, "Choice", str, self.options)
        self.dropDown.pack()
        if self.hasChild:
            self.child = MultiDropDownWidget(self.root, options[self.dropDown.value()], isChild=True)
        else:
            pass
 
 
    def updateChild(self, *args):
        if self.hasChild:
            self.child.destroyChildren()
            self.child = MultiDropDownWidget(self, self.originalOptions[self.dropDown.value()], isChild=True)
 
 
    def destroyChildren(self, *args):
        if self.hasChild:
            self.child.destroyChildren()
            self.child.destroy()
        if not self.hasChild:
            self.destroy()
            
 
options = {'a': {
            'aa': {'aaa': 'aaa'},
            'ab': {'aba': 'aba'},
            },
           'b': {
                'bb': {'bbb': 'bbb'},
                'bc': {'bcc': 'bcc'},
                 },
           'c':
               {'c1': {'c2': 'c2'}}}
root = tk.Tk()
multiWidget = MultiDropDownWidget(root, options)
multiWidget.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem seems to lie within destroyChildren()
I can see that the destroy()s are being called on the correct objects when using the debugger, but they are lingering around for some reason. I have also noticed that if I destroy the root widget they will all be destroyed, as expected.

I am also able to destroy their inner DropDownWidget without issue, but their empty frame and the MultiDropDownWidget still exist.

I tried making the MultiDropDown Frame.**init** make the frame show a blue background, but I'm not seeing the blue show up anywhere, which is probably where the issue lies. I'm still not sure why a component is resisting being destroyed.

If you replace the dropDown command with when hasChild is True with updateChildren you'll see the new children be generated without the old children being destroyed.

Comment: you can actually simply destroy the parent you don't have to recursively destroy each child individually

Comment: Yes, as Matiiss says, destroying the parent automatically destroys all children.

Comment: I'm trying to preserve the base optionmenu that the rest of them are constructed from, but I think I can restructure to account for that. Thanks.

Comment: On second thought, I'd still like to preserve any options that don't need to be destroyed, and only destroy and remake children that require it. Any idea why the children aren't being destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

I have restructured the widgets not to be their own MultiDropDownWidget objects but DropDownWidget objects that are stored in a list of the MultiDropDownWidget. Two issues that it has which should be okay for my use are that if a top-level key leads directly to a value, it crashes, and sub-options can't have the same value as an option preceding it when it is changed or it will reconfigure improperly.

```
class MultiDropDownWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, options, isChild=False):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, relief="raised", bg="blue")
        self.originalOptions = options
    
        if isChild is False:
            self.root = self
        else:
            self.root = self
    
        if isinstance(options, dict):
            if isinstance(list(options.values())[0], dict):
                self.options = {key: key for key in options.keys()}
                self.hasChild = True
            else:
                self.options = {key: value for key, value in options.items()}
                self.hasChild = False
    
        else:
            raise TypeError("DropDownWidgets take dictionaries of the choices and the values they represent as keys and values")
    
        self.widgets = []
        self.widgetValues = []
        self.valueLabel = FreeInputWidget(self, "Value", str)
        self.baseChoice = self.dropDown = DropDownWidget(self.root, "Choice", str, self.options,
                                            command=lambda x: self.reconstructChildren(x))
        self.widgets.append(self.baseChoice)
        self.baseChoice.pack()
        self.constructChildren(oOptions=self.originalOptions[self.baseChoice.value()])
        self.valueLabel.pack()
        #disableInput(self.valueLabel)
    
    
    
    
    def constructChildren(self, *args, oOptions="", widgetList=""):
        options = oOptions
        while True:
            b = False
            if isinstance(options, dict):
                if isinstance(list(options.values())[0], dict):
                    childoptions = {key: key for key in options.keys()}
                    command = self.reconstructChildren
                    child = DropDownWidget(self.root, "Choice", str, childoptions, command=lambda x: self.reconstructChildren(x))
                    self.root.widgets.append(child)
                    child.pack()
                    options = options[child.value()]
                else:
                    b = True
                    childoptions = {key: value for key, value in options.items()}
                    child = DropDownWidget(self.root, "Choice", str, childoptions, command=self.updateValueLabel)
                    self.root.widgets.append(child)
                    child.pack()
            else:
                pass
            # child = DropDownWidget(self.root, "Choice", str, childoptions, command=command)
            # self.root.widgets.append(child)
            # child.pack()
    
            if b is True:
                break
            else:
                pass
                # options = options[child.value()]
        self.updateValueLabel()
    
    def updateValueLabel(self, *args):
        self.valueLabel.setValue(self.widgets[len(self.widgets)-1].value())
        self.valueLabel.pack_forget()
        self.valueLabel.pack()
    
    def destroyChildren(self, index, *args):
        for child in self.widgets[index:]:
            # print(f"{child.value()} destroyed")
            child.pack_forget()
            self.widgets.pop(self.widgets.index(child))
            child.destroy()
    
    
    def reconstructChildren(self, x, *args):
        # print(self.widgets)
        i = 0
        for widget in self.widgets:
            # print(x, widget.value())
            if x == widget.value():
                break
            i += 1
        # print(x)
        # print(i)
        self.destroyChildren(i+1)
        newOptions = self.getDictLayer(i)#self.originalOptions, i, keyy)[keyy] #[keyy]
        self.constructChildren(oOptions=newOptions) #self.widgets[i].originalOptions)
    
    def getDictLayer(self, index, *args):
        options = self.originalOptions
        if index == 0:
            return options[self.baseChoice.value()]
        for i in range(0, index+1):
            # print(self.widgets[i].value())
            options = options[self.widgets[i].value()]
        return options
```